# The contents of /var/log/faillog consists of repeating "@^"

Tags: linux, logging, ubuntu-16.04

When I try to view my faillog with `nano /var/log/faillog` the log file is filled with nothing but "@^" over and over again. (I have also tried running the command with sudo, but the contents of the file dont' change)

What would cause the faillog to fill with these 2 characters specifically?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a single character `^@`, which stands for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd>, which is the NULL (0x00) character.

As for why they're there, `/var/log/faillog` is a binary file that is processed by `/usr/bin/faillog`  See `man 8 faillog` for more information on using it.

Comment: Thank you @DerfK! I didn't realize that the file was not human-readable.

Comment: The other useful one is `man 5 faillog`.